# What ISO of 22.04 supports the Intel platform? The LTS link is to ubuntu-22.04.4-live-server-amd64.iso?

Tags: 22.04, intel

I will be running a virtual server in a VMWARE instance on an Intel architecture. Minimally experienced with Ubuntu.  Any clarification would be appreciated.

Comment: The host OS needs  to support the underlying hardware, not the guest OS running in VMWARE.